# Can't apply patch SUPEE-6788 on Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7, patches, supee-6788

I'm trying to apply the SUPEE-6788 patch on Magento v 1.7.0.2
Here is a list of the current patches on the system:

```
2015-04-28 13:33:57 UTC | SUPEE-5345 | EE_1.12.0.2 | v1 | 2d36f61cf684ed26286b6d10307fcb99dd47ff02 | Thu Feb 5 19:39:01 2015 +0200 | v1.12.0.2..HEAD
2015-04-28 13:34:41 UTC | SUPEE-1533 | EE_1.12 | v1 | _ | n/a | SUPEE-1533_EE_1.12_v1.patch
2015-06-29 09:18:59 UTC | SUPEE-5994 | CE_1.6.0.0 | v1 | _ | n/a | SUPEE-5994_CE_1.6.0.0_v1.patch
2016-04-17 22:32:10 UTC | SUPEE-6285 | CE_1.7.0.2 | v1 | 84749c91e14543e1f96af30e86efdf29f4562c98 | Tue Jun 23 09:48:07 2015 +0300 | c6e6cee8eb..84749c91e1
```

As you can see I believe I have all the required security patches installed (which were released prior to this one)

However, when I try to do a dry-run, I get the folllowing:
(partial dump)

```
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php,

which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 

Apply anyway? [n] 

Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored

The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block.php,

which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 

Apply anyway? [n] 

Skipping patch.

1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block/Collection.php,

which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 

Apply anyway? [n] 

Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored

The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable.php,

which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 

Apply anyway? [n]
```

And so on.

It seems very odd to me.

Can someone assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new files that were introduced with this patch already exist and there is only one explanation: The patch already has been applied.

I don't know from where you got the information of already applied patches but it's wrong. A possible reason is that somebody applied the patch but did not commit `app/etc/applied.patches.list` to version control.